# RuntimeException occured when using Hbase to scan

Tags: hbase

Code:

> Filter filter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,new
> SubstringComparator(args[1]));
>
> Scan scan = new Scan();
>
> scan.setFilter(filter);
>
> ResultScanner res = table.getScanner(scan);
>
> for(Result r :res)  ***//LINE 49***
>
> {...}

I run this jar ,then i got the following exception message:

```
>     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after
> attempts=32, exceptions: Mon Dec 26 11:45:00 CST 2016, null,
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000,
> callDuration=60304: row '' on table 'maintable' at
> region=maintable,,1482293923088.ac4aebf960554591febc078e38ef5f08.,
> hostname=comp75,16020,1482598230057, seqNum=5645968
> 
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:97)
>         at com.beidu.hbaseutil.Query.main(Query.java:49) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException:
> Failed after attempts=32, exceptions: Mon Dec 26 11:45:00 CST 2016,
> null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000,
> callDuration=60304: row '' on table 'maintable' at
> region=maintable,,1482293923088.ac4aebf960554591febc078e38ef5f08.,
> hostname=comp75,16020,1482598230057, seqNum=5645968
> 
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:264)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:199)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:56)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:287)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:367)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:94)
>         ... 1 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=60304: row '' on table 'maintable' at
> region=maintable,,1482293923088.ac4aebf960554591febc078e38ef5f08.,
> hostname=comp75,16020,1482598230057, seqNum=5645968
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:294)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:275)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Call to comp75/172.16.249.75:16020 failed on
> local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallTimeoutException:
> Call id=2, waitTime=60002, operationTimeout=60000 expired.
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.wrapException(RpcClientImpl.java:1235)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1203)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:216)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:300)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:31751)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:199)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:62)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
>         ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallTimeoutException: Call id=2,
> waitTime=60002, operationTimeout=60000 expired.
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.checkAndSetTimeout(Call.java:70)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1177)
>         ... 12 more
```

Could anyone give some clues?thx

Comment: seems that Configuration has wrong setup

Comment: What are your `args[1]`? Have you looked at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14330?

Answer (score 0):

In this case scanner that you provided,is carrying out tasks which execute for a time interval more than the specified timeout.(callTimeout=60000, callDuration=60304).

If you are connected to the cluster then either you need to optimize your cluster/table/schema for reads,or change the timeout and in case you need huge scan,go for map-reduce.